# Question on "Cannot resolve symbol" when trying to import files from Android 19 API

Tags: android, android-studio, importerror

I am using Android Studio and getting the error, "cannot resolve symbol" when trying to import the following libraries:

```
import android.os.ServiceManager;
import android.os.storage.IMountService;
import android.os.storage.StorageEventListener;
```

Why do I get these errors? I can view the files ServieManager.java, IMountService.java, and StorageEventListener.java in Android Studio (Press Shift twice, and type in the file name - ServiceManager.java for example - and verify the file shows up. My IDE recognizes the file is there).

Looking at the attached picture below, it seems ServiceManager.java is part of the android 19 API:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of those classes are part of the Android SDK. For example, you will not find them in the published documentation. They are part of the *implementation* of Android, but they are not part of the public API of Android.

As a result, Android SDK projects cannot reference them.

Comment: So there is no way to import these libraries?

Comment: @Tim: They are not libraries. They are Java classes/interfaces. They are not part of the Android SDK. There is no requirement for them to exist on any particular device, unless you are building your own version of Android (e.g., for custom hardware).

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I have upvoted you and chosen your answer.